# How to parse date/time of the following format?

Tags: date, parsing, datetime, go, time

I have time strings of the following format

```
November 05, 2016, 01:02:31 PM
```

Does any one know how can I parse them into golang `Time`?

Comment: @natel: standard ```time.Parse``` function with layout set to above date string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

```
time.Parse(`January 02, 2006, 15:04:05 PM`, `November 05, 2016, 01:02:31 PM`)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LOD5D-8i_U